# 10 Amp Current Limit

Tags: power-supply, batteries, mosfet, battery-charging, high-current

I have a 28VDC, high current supply (constant voltage) that is required to charge an emergency power supply.

These EPS internals are rated at 15 amps max input current, however, it’s stipulated that I must regulate at 10 amps.

Issue is my power supply can supply 80+ amps nominal (as it charges multiple units). I’m thinking of a 10 amp limiting circuit using a mosfet and op amp for feedback?

Please advise me on anything - I’m still a student.

Comment: What is that EPS, technically? Just a stack of batteries? Batteries of which type, chemically? Usually, you'd charge with some kind of charge controller, not just with a straight (and dangerously powerful, 80 A 28 V is 2.24 kW) power supply.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but you should know that BJTs are safer for varying resistance to limit amperage than MOSFETs. MOSFETs are almost all designed for switching, and they have a failure mode that's usually not described in the datasheets. If you want to learn more, tag me and I'll find the past questions I've asked on this topic. Use a Darlington or dedicated regulator to regulate current, not a MOSFET.

Comment: Also not an answer: have you calculated how much power you would dissipate as your regulator steps 28 V down to a little bit above the battery's level while running 10 amps? It's probably enough to fry most small chips without a great heat sink. So I suspect the answer will involve a switching voltage regulator followed by a current regulator, or a system that does both.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it has internal circuitry for reverse polarity protection, over voltage and over current protection. In theory it’s designed so you could just apply 28VDC at an infinite potential of current and it wouldn’t go over 15 amps. But for safety it’s asked to regulate at 10. If the batteries are flat the initial surge will be very high as these are 5AH 2V lead acid cells, in series.

Comment: @piojo actually mosfets are becoming the industry leading technology for charging and discharging batteries now. Take the irfp4229 for example. They can regulate high current and allow easy integration with micro controllers. I haven’t done much work with bjt’s in all honesty, so I have little sway to working with them...

Comment: @TomMarshall Thanks for that. A quick look at the data sheet shows the safe operating area is not specified for longer than 100 microseconds. Since the failure mode I'm describing is not caused by power dissipation, the SOA curve is all I have to go by, and it doesn't say it can handle it. Infineon wrote an AN about this usage, but it's over my head: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ApplicationNote_Linear_Mode_Operation_Safe_Operation_Diagram_MOSFETs-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=db3a30433e30e4bf013e3646e9381200

Comment: Also, it seems confusing that linear regulation would be becoming an industry standard for charging/discharging. Excess voltage becomes heat. Is that really the direction the industry is moving in?

Comment: @piojo did you use fig.1 on the datasheet? It doesn’t seem to show the full Vds curve anywhere so I don’t think you would have seen the full soa, although I might be mistaken. It was purely an example. Everyone is always after a linear regulator for battery charging, unfortunately batteries can be very volatile and smps, for example, is a poor choice for charging unless very well designed. As you say, heat is the issue, but if correctly designed you won’t have any problems. Yes, mosfets and microcontrollers are currently the biggest upcoming developments. Primarily for automation.

Comment: @TomMarshall I was looking at figure 12, which does imply that a longer pulse has a smaller SOA. But I don't have the experience to analyze this further.

Comment: @piojo oh yes, I missed that! That is indeed correct. There are around 20 used within our chargers, so I guess fast pulsing and multiple of them does the job... when they come up for calibration I’ll try and borrow one. Get a scope on the gate and see the pulse width

Comment: @TomMarshall That makes sense, and jives better with what I've heard. I never thought of combining MOSFETs to get around this problem! That would be such an interesting circuit (to use MOSFETs like a very high power linear transistor and get around the silicone hotspot problem). But I'm not sure how this would be cheaper than using BJTs, which only need to be paralleled to so they stay within power/current limits. Maybe the economics is different at scale.

Comment: @piojo yeah they’re exactly that, being used as a linear regulator. The issue with this new technology is actually the voltages. Current sense is made using current sense resistors and a feedback circuit. But the voltage sense is done by an ADC, which as you may know are notoriously inaccurate (unless extremely precise components are used) and even more so at low voltages which batteries can be. If you can come up with an ADC that’s precise with a large bandwidth then you’re laughing. The guy that makes them says they’re fine but my flukes tell me otherwise ;) sorry bit off tangent 

Answer (score 1):

Well, here’s a simple way: use a 10A PTC resettable fuse. Like these: https://m.littelfuse.com/~/media/electronics/datasheets/resettable_ptcs/littelfuse_ptc_radial_leaded_ruef_datasheet.pdf.pdf

Comment: Great! I’ve used these before on ac circuitry, I’ll have a look at some. Didn’t even think about them. Thank you